# probability: Chebyshev inequality question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, logarithms, random-variables

For this question, **I don't understand the highlighted part of the solution
I thought it should be >5, but then 6?**
 [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\log_2R$, and hence $|\log_2R-80|$ are integers. Therefore, the **complement of** the event $|\log_2R-80|\le 5$ is the event $|\log_2R-80|\ge 6$.

Comment: It is a little bit weird. I know R is a number between 2^(75) and 2^(85), but it doesn't mean that R can't be 2^(76.6). In this case, then it is not an integer. But I see your point.

Comment: No R cannot be 2^(76.6).